# How to make Geany understand the new HTML5 elements?

Tags: 11.10, settings, text-editor, ide, geany

For example `<header>` and `<footer>` are new HTML5 elements, but as it seems in the screen shot below both the elements are marked as red which probably means Geany is telling :
 **Warining : Unknown elements**

[image: Geany doesn't know what is header and footer elements]

How can I make this normal? What files do I need to edit?

### Update

I found that when I revert back to default (white background, as shown in [Morlunk](https://askubuntu.com/a/136580/49715)'s answer) theme then no error occurs. Any way to make this happen in my theme? **Because I don't want to leave dark theme**

Answer (score 4):

On the version of Geany shipped with Ubuntu 12.04 (0.21), this doesn't appear to be an issue!

I recommend you update to the latest version of Geany using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~geany-dev/+archive/ppa/) or, if you're feeling adventurous, updating to Ubuntu 12.04. Good luck!

Andrew

[image: Geany 0.21]

Comment: I think the problem is with my theme I downloaded, because when I reverted back to normal theme then it shows no such error. But I can't leave that theme!

Answer (score 3):

The following can be tacked onto the end of the HTML keywords line in `filetypes.xml` (`~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.xml`) for the HTML5 new elements to be recognised:

```
article aside audio canvas command details datalist figure figcaption footer header hgroup keygen mark meter nav output progress section time video wbr
```

(Geany 1.23.1 has these keywords.)